# How to use route options (replace=true) in a link generated with route-href?

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible for a `route-href` generated link to have the `replace=true` option when `pushState` is enabled?

I have tried:

```
<a route-href="route: user/details; options.bind: {replace: true}">Link</a>
```

and it does not work. There is no error and the view changes but after clicking the link a new item in the browser history appears (and it should not).

Comment: `route-href` is a custom-attribute that generates an `href` attribute with the corresponding URL. I don't think it's possible to specify `replace=true` in the URL

Comment: But a similar attribute [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) from Angular UI Router has an additional `ui-sref-opts` param that can be used to set the options like `replace` directly in the view. I suppose it handles the clicks behind the scenes to do that...

Comment: Yeah problably, but that's not the case in aurelia. `route-href` just generates you an `href` attribute. I'm looking at the source-code and there's no `options` bindable property. You'd have to handle the click event

Comment: This would be a good feature to add. Maybe you could create a feature request on [aurelia/templating-router repository](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/issues)?

Comment: I have created a [feature request](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/issues/54).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The `route-href` generates an `href` attribute containing the url to the specified route. To navigate to a route using `replace: true` you'd have to create a method in your view-model and call this method using a `click` event. Something like this:

**ViewModel**

```
goToRoute() {
   this.route.navigateToRoute('myRoute', { id:'someId' }, { replace: true });
}
```

**View**

```
<a click.delegate="goToRoute()"></a>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because it does not work with middle-click (i.e. "open in new tab"). I am trying to figure out something with additional custom attribute (`route-href-options`). It should hijack the click, read the href of the element and then use the router to navigate with options. However, I am unable to do the first part with "hijacking". Even if i set `onclick="return false"` on the element, it is still handled with aurelia router and the view changes.

Comment: Wait, if you are opening in a new tab why you need `replace`?

Comment: I want to have an ability to open in new tab (users get angry when there is a link and middle button does nothing). The replace option should work only with normal clicks.

Comment: I know that, what I'm saying is that since you are opening in a new tab the `replace` shouldn't be necessary, right? Perhaps I misunderstood what you want to achieve, or I don't fully understand what `replace: true` does

Comment: When opening in new tab, `replace` does not work (there should be a single entry in the browser history with current page). What I'm trying to achive is that if user open the links normally, then the history is not populated (`replace: true`), but if he wants to open the same link in a new tab, he should be allowed to (your solution fails here).